# File.separator on Unix based system

Tags: java, unix

I developed an desktop application which does some File writing n reading operations. To get path of file I used this code :

```
static final String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

public static final String resourcesPath = 
    workingDir + File.separator + "src" + File.separator;
```

in windows variable `resourcesPath` contains `C:\app\src\`but when I execute application on unix based system this returns me `/home/eboss\src\`.

In unix based system `/home/eboss` is the path from `System.getProperty("user.dir");` which is correct but when I concat with `File.separator` it appends path with `\` this. in result I get (No such file or directory) error.

why unix based system returning wrong path.?

Comment: I would take the file seperator from the system properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Why use anything but "/" anyway? Is there an OS that doesn't understand "/"?

Comment: I'm having trouble believing that this actually happens with the code shown (it doesn't for me). Are you using the Sun/Oracle JVM and JDK? What system are you compiling on (not that it should matter)? Are you using something that takes the Java bytecode and turns it into "native" code?

Comment: @user503413: In theory, that's just a long-winded way to get the same thing.

Comment: A comment that has nothing to do with the original question: Constants such as `workingDir` or `resourcePath` are normally written entirely in uppercase characters. So `WORKING_DIR` and `RESOURCE_PATH` would be the widely accepted way of naming those fields.

Comment: Why? 'user.dir' is just '.' from the application's point of view. You don't need to prefix it to anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am compiling this on windows Oracle JDK but where I m executing jar on unix having Sun Runtime...

Comment: @Amogh: I'm unable to replicate your results using your code. When I compile using Oracle JDK7 on Windows and run it on Linux, I get the correct file separator on both platforms. Fundamentally you should not be getting that result. Something in your environment is corrupted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried with `System.getProperty("file.separator")` but is also giving me the same result(as you said in answer comment).. is this coz of different JDK while compilation and different runtime at execution...I am using eduBoss OS where I m executing jar (http://bosslinux.in/eduboss)

Comment: @Amogh - no it is irrelevant where and how you compiled it, but the JDK/JRE on your "bosslinux" is very probably broken.

Comment: @Amogh: Probably half the point of Java is that it works correctly when you compile on one OS and run the result on another. As Ingo said, whatever JVM you're using when running it appears to be broken. I wouldn't use it. The Sun/Oracle JVM will work correctly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder will try to reinstall runtime...and let you know.

Comment: I can’t imagine that there’s a JVM being that broken. It’s more likely that your startup configuration has issues. E.g. providing `-Dfile.separator=X` on the command line or equivalent would be a way to get into trouble…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's a problem with the JVM you're using to run this on Unix.

Provided that:

- You're using a correct JVM, such as the one from Sun/Oracle, and
- You aren't overwriting that JVM's `jar` files with ones from your Windows JVM

...that code will work correctly. You'll want to re-install the JVM and ensure you're not overwriting any JVM jars.

(I wasn't able to get my Linux JVM to use a Windows `rt.jar` [the one that contains `File.class`], but I wouldn't 100% guarantee it isn't possible. When I tried, the best I could do was get my JVM to refuse to initialize.)

Comment: I am using eduBoss OS where I m executing jar (bosslinux.in/eduboss).So as per commets on question and answer by @T.J.Crowder There may some problem in `JVM` on that OS.I overcome the problem by changing my code whenever i am taking any path and if that path contains `"\\"` i replced to `"/"`